# System.NullReferenceException when unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I am new to unit testing,

I am working on a minimal API project. and I am testing an endpoint with xunit, moq

endpoint class - ParticipantsGetAll.cs

```
public class ParticipantsGetAll : IEndpoint<IResult, GetAllParticipantsRequest>
{
    const string uri = "api/participants-all";
    private ParticipantService? participantService;

    public void AddRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapPost(uri, async ( ParticipantService participantService, [FromBody] GetAllParticipantsRequest query) => 
        {
            this.participantService = participantService;
            return await HandleAsync(query);
        })
        .Produces<List<ParticipantSummaryModel>>()
        .WithTags("Participants")
        .WithName("GetAllParticipants");
    }

    public async Task<IResult> HandleAsync( GetAllParticipantsRequest query)
    {
        var participants = await participantService!.ListAllAsync(query);
        return Results.Ok(participants);
    }
```

I tried to write a unit test test above endpoint class.

CreateParticipantApiTest.cs

```
    [Fact]
    public async void ListAllAsyncShouldReturn200Status()
    {
        var query = new GetAllParticipantsRequest()
        {
           Name= "",
            KeyCordinator="",
            RelatedConnection="",
            Statuses = null

        };
        var participant = ParticipantMockData.NewParticipantModel(); // a static class

        var sut = new ParticipantsGetAll();
        var result = (OkObjectResult)await sut.HandleAsync(query);

        result.StatusCode.Should().Be(200);

    }
```

I got below error

> Message: 
> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Stack Trace: 
> ParticipantsGetAll.HandleAsync(GetAllParticipantsRequest query) line 36
> CreateParticipantApiTest.ListAllAsyncShouldReturn200Status() line 67

I have no idea why the object tis null.

Please anyone help me to find the problem.
I am facing this issue for a long time

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea why the object tis null.

That is pretty clear, because in your unit test you invoke `HandleAsync` directly, so the setup which you have moved into `MapPost` does not happen (compiler was trying to help but was shut down with null-forgiving operator in `participantService!.ListAllAsync(query)`). Also I'm pretty sure this way of using handlers can lead to some concurrency problems (if `ParticipantService` is a scoped service). Move `ParticipantService participantService` to `HandleAsync`. Something along this lines (not tested):

```cs
public class ParticipantsGetAll : IEndpoint<IResult, GetAllParticipantsRequest>
{
    const string uri = "api/participants-all";

    public void AddRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapPost(uri, HandleAsync)
        .Produces<List<ParticipantSummaryModel>>()
        .WithTags("Participants")
        .WithName("GetAllParticipants");
    }

    public async Task<IResult> HandleAsync(ParticipantService participantService, [FromBody] GetAllParticipantsRequest query)
    {
        var participants = await participantService.ListAllAsync(query);
        return Results.Ok(participants);
    }
}
```

And modify the test accrodingly.

Comment: Thanks. 
Can I create a constructor inside `ParticipantsGetAll` like below. 
`public ParticipantsGetAll(ParticipantService participantService)
    {
        this.participantService = participantService;
    }`

Comment: @hanushi you can but there is no point in doing so in current code structure.